# ASP.NET MVC Control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-controls, recommendation-engine

Can anybody recommend a combobox/drop down list control that also has checkboxes on each row?  It would also need to support multi select.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [RadComboBox](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/combobox.aspx) along with a little tweaking as provided for by this telerik community project, found [here](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-ajax/combobox/radcombobox-advanced-multiple-selection.aspx#517725).

Should all work fine in MVC.

Answer (score 0):

there one from [SyncFusion.com](http://mvc.syncfusion.com/sfmvcsamplebrowser/9.2.0.138/Tools_MVC/Samples/4.0/Razor/genericdropdown/databinding) with code for both Razor and aspx but I doubt you'll be able to find a free one.